# Derivative of $f(x)= {\sqrt{x^2-1}\over x}$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, fractions

I have the function following:

$$f(x)= {\sqrt{x^2-1}\over x}$$

And here is what I did:

$$f(x)= {\sqrt{x^2-1}\over x}$$

$$ = {{(x^2-1)^{1 \over 2}} \over x}$$
$$f'(x) = { x \cdot {1 \over 2} (x^2-1)^{-{1 \over 2}} (2x) - (x^2 - 1)^{1 \over 2}\over x^2}$$
$$=\frac {x^2 (x^2 -1)^{-{\frac {1}{2}}} - (x^2 -1)^{\frac {1}{2}}}{x^2}$$
And I'm pretty sure that this is wrong, and the answer book says it isn't either.

I think I messed up somewhere, or didn't do it properly.

I tried using the quotient rule. Do I need to make it into an exponent, and solve it as a chainrule?

Please help me find the steps and answer to this question. Thank you.

Or is there any other steps so it can match  this?:

$$\frac {1}{x^2 \sqrt{x^2 -1}}$$

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: It is correct.  Just multiply your numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{x^2-1}$ and it simplifies to the answer at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}$$
$$f(x) = \frac{u}{v}$$
Note that $u = \sqrt{x^2-1}$, $v = x$, and $v' = 1$We then note that $u' = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$
$$f'(x) = \frac{u'v - uv'}{v^2}$$
$$ = \frac{\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-1}} - \sqrt{x^2-1}}{x^2}$$
$$ = \frac{\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-1}} + \frac{-(x^2-1)}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}} {x^2}$$
$$ = \frac{\frac{x^2 - x^2 - 1}{\sqrt{x^21}}}{x^2}$$
$$ = \frac{1}{x^2\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

Comment: I had to delete my post for about 5 minutes as I misread the question... I  came back to the problem and did what you asked, but someone else beat me to it... Man people on here are quick!

Answer (score 2):

All your steps are fine, but your final answer can be simplified further to match the answer in your book.
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^2(x^2-1)^{-1/2}-(x^2-1)^2}{x^2} &= \frac{\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}-\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x^2}\\
&=\frac{\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}-\frac{x^2-1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}}{x^2}\\
&=\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}}{x^2}\\
&= \frac{1}{x^2{\sqrt{x^2-1}}}
\end{align*}